# Moving True and False values in DE stored as text into Boolean

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio, sql

I am trying to run a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
Email_Address As emailAddress,
Firstname As firstName,
OptIn_Education As optInEdu,
OptIn_Commercial As optInCom
FROM [Old_DE]
```

The problem I am having is that the OptIn_Education and OptIn_Commercial values are stored in Old_DE as text ('Yes' and 'No') but the new data extension holds these as Boolean. When trying to run this query in an Automation it fails, with the error message:

> Query failed during execution. Error: Conversion failed when
>   converting the nvarchar value 'No' to data type bit.

Is there a way of converting it to Boolean easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be able to do something like this with a CASE statement

```
SELECT
  Email_Address As emailAddress
, Firstname As firstName
, case 
    when OptIn_Education in ('yes','OK','on','roger that','yup') then 1 
    else 0 
  end As optInEdu
, case 
    when OptIn_Commercial in ('yes','OK','on','roger that','yup') then 1 
    else 0 
  end As optInCom
FROM [Old_DE]
```